# Nothing happening when I do enter java <name> on shell (It gives me no output or errors but seems to be processing for a bit)

Tags: java, shell, compilation, ide, command

I built this project on NetBeans, and it runs fine from there. I can't get it to run on Shell.

The directory is .../AStarVacuum/src/astarvacuum

astarvacuum's contents are: 
AStarVacuum.java  Node.java  VacuumUtils.java  Grid.java
AStarVacuum.class  Node.class  VacuumUtils.class  Grid.class

The main function is in AStarVacuum. The other java class files are also part of this project.

When I enter the command "java AStarVacuum" nothing happens other than shell lagging for a bit if I enter any other commands. I've waited without doing anything for it to do something for 30 minutes or so, even, but it gives me not output whatsoever.

Here is the code for the class containing main:

```
//package astarvacuum; from netbeans, commented out for shell
public class AStarVacuum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
...
 }

}
```

And, here is the code for another class. The others were pretty similar:

```
//package astarvacuum;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Thread;
public class Node {
...
}
```

I'm kind of a newb at this; I usually use ides, but my professor wants me to submit this to a server and be able to run this from shell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in some of the code you haven't shown us - e.g. you've got an infinite loop.

Comment: There are no infinite loops, though there is a long loop and some deep recursion. It does work on my slow laptop though, so I don't think that's the issue. I'm going to try running it on different ides and see if I get errors and hopefully weed out anything that was netbeans specific.

Comment: I'd be *incredibly* surprised if it's Netbeans-specific, but it's very hard to tell what's going on with so little information.

Comment: I figured it out. Its the server. I compiled it on the server, downloaded it and ran it, and it worked fine. I don't know why it doesn't work on the server, but there's probably not much I can do about it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call "figuring it out" - we could still potentially help you figure it out, but again, not without seeing some code.